# vba if statement returns "object variable or with block variable not set" error

Tags: excel, vba

can someone please help me understand why my `If` statement is returning this error and how to better perform the intended task?

the goal of this `Sub` is to copy company records/sales from sheet `src` to sheet `des`, but where there are multiple records for a company, i want to sum the sales and only have one record on `des`. it does this by grabbing a company name from `src` first, then checking if it exists in `des`.

```
Sub populate_sales()
    slr = src.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For r = 2 To slr
        dlr = des.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        c_name = src.Range("M" & r).Value
        Dim d_names As Range
        Set d_names = des.Range("A1", des.Range("A" & dlr + 1))

        If d_names.Find(c_name) = False Then
            ' start the summing + writing process
        Else
            ' skip to next next record
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

for the record, although you only see `d_names` defined here, all variables are defined i just do it globally for those used by multiple subs. in fact, as long as `c_name` already exists in the `d_names` range, the `If` statement works and it skips to the next company. however if the company doesn't exist in `d_names` then the error is returned highlighting `If d_names.Find(c_name) = False Then`.

any help the community can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Set d_names = des.Range(des.Range("A1"), des.Range("A" & dlr + 1))`

Comment: You can do this with simple SumIfs Function. Copy src M Column to des A Column.. Sort it.. remove duplicates... apply sumifs function.. Sumifs (src Sales Columns, des A column, company name in corresponding des A column row).. ... And if you need VBA, you can put this procedure in a macro with worksheetfunction.sumifs

Comment: You can use range.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True for selecting unique company names in des

Comment: Haven't tested - `If not d_names.find(c_name) is nothing then`

Comment: Note, when using the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) it is **absolutely necessary** to specify the `LookAt` argument either as `xlWhole` or `xlPart`. If you don't do that, your code will use whatever was used last by either VBA or the user interface (there is no default)! So if you don't specify it, your code randomly behaves differently.

Comment: @peh same argument applies to LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder and MatchByte, as your link explains.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - thanks for that solution. i was assuming `d_names.Find` would return a boolean value. such a simple solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will help you to understand `Find Method`

```
Sub populate_sales()

    Dim rngFound As Range, rngSearchIn As Range
    Dim strSearchFor As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'Set the value you want to search for
        strSearchFor = "Test"

        'Set the range you want to search in
        Set rngSearchIn = .Range("A1:A5")

        Set rngFound = rngSearchIn.Find(strSearchFor, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)

        If rngFound Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Values not found."
        Else
            MsgBox "Values found."
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: NOTE: although i up-voted @DarrenBartrup-Cook's comment for pointing out my error, i'm marking this as 'the answer' seeing as it give a broader explanation of the process (as well as solves the issue). thanks Error 1004.

Comment: It's also an answer as defined by SO - mine was just a comment.  I didn't want to add it as an actual answer as was on my phone so couldn't do any testing and writing full answers is so much harder on a small touch-screen. :)